# Pythonic way to access constant global scoped variables inside of a class?

Tags: python

Say I have the following code:

```python
import threading

class Check(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, item):
        super(Check, self).__init__()
        self._item = item

    def run(self):
        data = '{} ({} total)'.format(self._item, total)
        collected.append(data)

items = ['item{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(5)]
total = len(items)
collected = []
for item in items: Check(item).start()
```

(Let's cast aside the uselessness of the above code. Its only purpose here is to aid in explaining the question.)

Is there a more Pythonic way to access `total` and `collected` from inside of the `run` method of the `Check` class? The value of `total` is guaranteed not to change. I cannot pass anything else to the `run` method as far as I know. Passing the same `total` and `collected` values to the constructor of the `Check` class seems silly, but perhaps it's the best practice?

Comment: Why not make them class attributes? Looking at the use-case, looks like it is required to have only one instance of those. (and then you can access them inside an instance method also as `self.total` and `self.collected`. And anywhere outside as `Check.total` and `Check.collected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a lock in the code and here is one approach to do it.

`collected`, `total` are class variable and since it's a shared state, it's better to protect it with a lock. Note having an instance variable as `lock` would defeat the purpose, so it's a class variable.

```
import threading

class Check(threading.Thread):
    collected = []
    total = 0
    lock = threading.Lock()
    def __init__(self, item):
        super(Check, self).__init__()
        self._item = item

    def run(self):
        data = '{} ({} total)'.format(self._item, self.total)
        with self.lock:
            self.collected.append(data)

items = ['item{}'.format(i) for i in range(5)]
Check.total = len(items)
for item in items:
    Check(item).start()

print (Check.total)
print (Check.collected)
```

Answer (score 3):

`global` and threading isn't a great mix. At the very least, if you're mutating shared state, you should have locks in place, and `global` is about the most extreme case of "shared" state that you can have.

I'd definitely recommend passing both `item` and `total` into your `Check` class, and retrieving the value from your thread instead and "assembling" it later:

```
import threading

class Check(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, item, total):
        super(Check, self).__init__()
        self._item = item
        self._total = total
        self.result = None

    def run(self):
        data = '{} ({} total)'.format(self._item, self._total)
        self.result = data

 items = ['item{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(5)]
 total = len(items)
 collected = []

 checks = [Check(item) for item in items]
 for check in checks:
     check.start()
 for check in checks:
     check.join()
 collected = [check.result for check in checks]
```

But if you can use Python 3, an even better way would be to avoid subclassing `Thread` and dealing with them directly in the first place:

```
 from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

 def do_check(item, total):
     data = '{} ({} total)'.format(self._item, self._total)
     return data

 items = ['item{}'.format(i) for i in range(5)]
 total = len(items)

 tpe = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
 collected = list(tpe.map(lambda item: do_check(item, total), items))
```

No `global`s, no threads, and less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely sure that you will always use the same global variables in your function, and the global variables will never change, then there's no need to use parameters.

The most pythonic way to do it would be to explicitly specify that `total` and `collected` are global variables using the `global` keyword:

```
def run(self):
    global total
    global collected

    data = '{} ({} total)'.format(self._item, total)
    collected.append(data)
```